# How to open loads of links at once?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to test long list of links to see if they're real links or broken, i had the daft idea that rather than just click them one at a time, open every one at once, the work my way through the open tabs. The html looks something like this:

```
<a href="www.somelink.com"></a>
<a href="www.somelink.com"></a>
<a href="www.somelink.com"></a>
<a href="www.somelink.com"></a>
```

with the jQuery being:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('a').attr('target','_blank');
  $('a').click();
});
```

The `target="_blank"` works just fine, but the `click` does not, why is my browser not going crazy and trying to open 50 news pages at once?

Comment: Are the number of 'clicks' coinciding with the number of anchors in your html? Id look up how Jquery selectors work again.

Comment: this is done for obvious security reasins...would you want your browser opening all sorts of unexpected windows/pages/sites just beacuse someone can throw that in a script?

Comment: i half assumed that to be the case, but for running a local test site i wondered if there was a way round it. someone clearly doesn't like the question running round down voting! if it cant be done then it cant be done, cheers!

Comment: i wish you had to explain a downvote rather than just downvote without constructive feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WHat you can do is loop through the elements and capture their href and use `window.open`

```
$("a").each(function()  {
   window.open( this.href)
});
```

Comment: it can be done! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('a')[0].click();
```

But it will fire click on only first anchor tag.

Complete code:

```
$('a').attr('target','_blank');
alert("After this alert 4 link will open");
for(var i=0;i<=3;i++)
{
    $('a')[i].click();
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LT4UK/1/)